# refetch or poll an external API with fetch in svelte

Tags: svelte, fetch-api, sveltekit, polling

New to Svelte and am running into some issues.

Currently doing the following in +page.server.js
I would like to poll this API every couple hundred milliseconds, I am unsure how to do that. I have tried using set Interval here to no avail.

```
export async function load({params}) {
  const response = await fetch(
      `http://localhost:9595/api/v1/chrysalis/example?uid=${params.uid}`
  )
  const site = await response.json()
  const siteData = site[0]
  console.log(siteData)

  return {
    uid: params.uid,
    partitions: siteData.partitions,
    zones: siteData.zones,
    zTypes: siteData.zTypes,
    zStates: siteData.zStates,
    zNames: siteData.zNames
  }
}
```

For example, I've built this in next.Js using SWR with refreshInterval: 1.

```
  const {data, error, isLoading} = useSWR(
      'http://localhost:9595/api/v1/chrysalis/example',
      (url) => {
        const searchParams = new URLSearchParams();
        searchParams.append("uid", body.uid)
        const newUrl = `${url}?${searchParams.toString()}`
        const options = {
          method: 'GET',
          headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
        }
        return fetch(newUrl, options).then(res => res.json())
      },
      {
        refreshInterval: 1
      }
  );
```

I have also tried to do the following onMount of the +page.svelte but when trying to hit the API from the client I get CORS error.( ran into this before if +page.js was not +page.server.js

```
let x;

  onMount(async () => {
    setInterval(async () => {
      const response = await fetch(
          `http://localhost:9595/api/v1/chrysalis/example?uid=${data.uid}`
      )
      const site = await response.json()
      x = site[0]
      console.log(x)
    }, 3000)
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

The CORS error results because +page.svelte/+page.js are run in the browser. So you need to proxy the call through a service that allows being called from the browser. (Or relax the CORS restrictions on http://localhost:9595)

You can use SvelteKit itself to proxy the call by creating an internal [endpoint](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/routing#server). So:

1. The internal endpoint simply fetches `http://localhost:9595/api/foo/...` and returns the results. (You can just forward the response object from `fetch()`)
2. +page.svelte calls that internal endpoint from `setInterval()`.